# HTC One M9 factory reset problem

Tags: factory-reset, htc-one-m9

I need to do a factory reset on my HTC One M9. Just for clarification, I have not rooted the phone ever. I'm trying to do a factory reset through the phone setting and once I do the reset, it brings me to the bootloader. I'm not sure what to do from there. I try to boot it into recovery mode, but it says "this build is only for development purposes only"

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-- (for Hard Factory Reset)

1. Remove SD card and SIM card. Switch of your phone.
2. Press and hold **volume down key** along with **power button**, release the power button when vibrates.
3. Navigate to **reboot to bootloader** with volume keys and select with the power button.
4. Then select **BOOT TO RECOVERY MODE**.
5. Then select **wipe data/factory reset**.
6. Then **Yes – delete all user data**.

But as you mentioned that it says *"this build is only for development purposes only"*. Then you can try resetting from the setting menu.

The detailed process to reset M9 by setting menu and Hard Reset is given [here](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-31503).

If none of the methods works, then you may need to visit the service center.